# How do I use wildcards in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I am trying to write a function that will take in a string (formula in excel), and will replace any use of ISBLANK() with FALSE. This is what I am trying and cannot seem to get it to work.

```
temp = sheet[cellCord].value
temp = temp.replace("ISBLANK(*)", "FALSE")
sheet[cellCord].value = temp
```

Most of the time it will be in an early cell so I also tried using three '?'s instead of '*' but it still does not work. If you guys have any advice or good resources that could help I would appreciate it.

EDIT: An example of what I am trying to do is change

```
=IF(ISBLANK(W22), "", (X22/W13))
```

into

```
=IF(FALSE, "", (X22/W13))
```

Comment: Vanilla strings don't support wildcards or other dynamic behavior. [Try `re.sub()`, maybe?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a regex that captures exactly what you looking for, then replace only that, using `re.sub`

`r"ISBLANK\([^)]+\)"` -- `ISBLANK(` + "anything until a `)`", + `)`

```
In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.sub(r"ISBLANK\([^)]+\)", "FALSE", 'ISBLANK(W22)')
Out[3]: 'FALSE'

In [5]: re.sub(r"ISBLANK\([^)]+\)", "FALSE", '=IF(ISBLANK(W22), "", (X22/W13))')
Out[5]: '=IF(FALSE, "", (X22/W13))'
```

You could also split the text on a comma, then rebuild it with

```
'=IF(FALSE,' + ','.join(values[1:])
```

```
In [6]: values = '=IF(ISBLANK(W22), "", (X22/W13))'.split(',')

In [8]: '=IF(FALSE,' + ','.join(values[1:])
Out[8]: '=IF(FALSE, "", (X22/W13))'
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! Sorry about that previous comment, your answer had not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards in python can be implemented using re module. I believe you're trying to replace `ISBLANK("Anything inside this")` with `FALSE`.

Try using this instead:

```
import re

temp = sheet[cellCord].value
temp = re.sub(r"ISBLANK\([\w\d\.-_&%$@#\!^,\/\?'\"]*\)", "FALSE", temp)
sheet[cellCord].value = temp
```

Comment: I tried that and it worked but it deleted everything after as well.  I edited the question to better describe what I am trying to change.

Comment: @AlanJones `.*` means all trailing characters. The parenthesis here aren't needed

Comment: @OneCricketeer is there a way to make it stop after the closing parentheses. The ISBLANK() is part of an if statement and I want to preserve the rest of the if statement.

Comment: @AlanJones Yeah. See my answer

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried covering all the use cases that can come as a variable or string arguments. But your approach is better, checking anything till ')'. So, should I delete my answer?

Comment: Keeping it here as other possible solution.